# Не работает update, с WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

<p>Здравствуйте! Почему-то не работает <strong>update</strong>. Без WHERE id='$id' работает. В чём может быть проблема? Заранее благодарю за любую помощь</p>

```
<?php 
      include 'form/bd.php';/*Соедеиняемся с базой*/
     if (isset ($_POST['title']))            {$title = $_POST['title']; if ($title == '') {unset ($title);} }    
   if (isset ($_POST['description']))        {$description = $_POST['description']; if ($description == '') {unset ($description);} }
   if (isset ($_POST['price']))          {$price= $_POST['price']; if ($price == '') {unset ($price);} }
    if (isset ($_POST['image']))         {$image = $_POST['image']; if ($image == '') {unset ($image);} }
 if (isset ($_POST['cat']))   {$cat = $_POST['cat']; if ($cat == '') {unset ($cat);} }
   $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE page='index'",$db);
   $myrow = @mysql_fetch_array ($result); ?>
```

---

```
<?php 
if (isset ($title) && isset ($description) && isset ($price) && isset ($image) && isset ($cat))
{   
  $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE `products` SET title='".$title."',description='".$description."',price='".$price."',image='".$image."',cat='".$cat."' WHERE id='$id' ");
 if ($result == 'true') 
    { echo "<p>Продукт успешно обновлен!</p>";}
  else 
    { echo "<p>Хьюстон! У нас проблемы! Продукт не обновлен!</p>";}
}
 else
   {  echo "<p>Вы ввели не всю информацию, поэтому продукт не может быть обновлен в базу</p>"; } ?>
```

---

Comment: @Kokos, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуй так

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE `products` SET title='".$title."',description='".$description."', price='".$price."',image='".$image."',cat='".$cat."' WHERE id='".$id."' ");
```

**UPD**
[[@Kokos](/users/15103/kokos)](/users/15103/kokos), разобрался с проблемой. В форме редактирования продукта в action указано update_product.php. Но id в update_product.php не попадает, поэтому и не происходит обновления. Как вариант создайте input type=hidden

```
<label>Введите название продукта:<br>
<input value="$myrow[title]" type="text" name="title" id="title">
</label>
<input value="$myrow[id]" type="hidden" name="id">
</p>
```

и в него заносите id. И при отправке данных ловите $_POST['id]. Тогда все хорошо обновляется. **Важно!** Используйте функцию error_reporting(E_ALL) для отслеживания ошибок. Подключать ее нужно в самом начале скрипта. С ее помощью я и нашел проблему

Comment: @mountpoint, id -- не строковое значение же, наверное. Если только топикстартер не извращался.

Comment: mountpoint, попробовала. Нет изменений

Comment: @Risto, мускулу не важно как ты передашь значение id - строкой или числом, сработает в любом случае. Это факт.

@Kokos, этот запрос должен 100% сработать, если весь вышенаписанный скрипт правильный.

Comment: @mountpoint, а где может быть ошибка?

Comment: @Kokos, доберусь до работы, там и посмотрю) сейчас убагаю)

Comment: Ну сделайте вывод того что передается и все 

        print_r("UPDATE `products` SET title='".$title."',description='".$description."', price='".$price."',image='".$image."',cat='".$cat."' WHERE id='".$id."' ");

Если не работает с айди, а так работает, значит айди не передается вообще, кавычки можно оставлять.

Comment: @Kokos, вы смотрели, изменяются ли в базе записи?

Comment: @mountpoint, смотрела. Не изменяются записи в базе.

Comment: @Kokos, закиньте архив со всеми вашим проектом и базой данных на файлообменник http://rghost.ru/main и дайте ссылку

Comment: @mountpoint, благодарю! Все получилось))

Answer (score 1):

Это конечно может ни на что не повлиять, но если уж начинаешь выделять названия полей и таблиц обратными апострофами, то выделяй все. Мускул бывает строг в этом плане :)

Т.е. должно быть так:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE `products` SET `title`='".$title."', `description`='".$description."', `price`='".$price."', `image`='".$image."',`cat`='".$cat."' WHERE `id`='".$id."' ");
```

Comment: @nathaira, благодарю!